# Why R download package from old mran snapshot?

Tags: r

I use RStudio with microsoft R open, I recently realize that it install package from an old snapshot in 2016-11. How can I change this to force it to download from most recent snapshot? I use R version 3.3.2. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `?chooseCRANmirror`?